# Why std::sort doesn't accept Compare classes declared within a function

Tags: c++

I was at work, writing the Comparators in a function (to move later, when I decided where was best), and noticed this peculiarity.  I thought about it for a while, and realized I do not understand exactly why the code will not compile if I use the  inner comparators, but the outer one is fine.

Any explanations?

Quick Test harness:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class CompareMe
{
 public:
    CompareMe(int in) : toCompare(in){}
    int toCompare;
};

class Comparators
{
public:
    bool operator()(CompareMe * first, CompareMe * second)
    {
        return first->toCompare < second->toCompare;
    }
};

class ComparatorsOuter : public Comparators{};

int main()
{
    class ComparatorsInner : public Comparators{};

    std::vector<CompareMe *> compares;
    compares.push_back(new CompareMe(0));
    compares.push_back(new CompareMe(1234));
    compares.push_back(new CompareMe(163));
    compares.push_back(new CompareMe(6));
    compares.push_back(new CompareMe(12));

    //This works, and properly sorts the array
    ComparatorsOuter comparator;
    std::sort(compares.begin(), compares.end(), comparator);

    //Uncomment out the sort below and it will not compile.
    ComparatorsInner comparatorInner;
    //std::sort(compares.begin(), compares.end(), comparatorInner);

    std::vector<CompareMe *>::iterator it;
    for(it = compares.begin(); it != compares.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << (*it)->toCompare << std::endl;
    }
}
```

> error: no matching function for call to '`sort(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CompareMe**, std::vector<CompareMe*, std::allocator<CompareMe*> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CompareMe**, std::vector<CompareMe*, std::allocator<CompareMe*> > >, main()::ComparitorInner&)`'

Comment: What do you mean by `breaks down`? Perhaps you are using an older compiler?

Comment: I mean, it does not compile.  I will edit to clarify.

Comment: BTW it's spelt "comparator".

Comment: Template parameters must have global linkage, because the result has it.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/E5X5vM) works on C++11 and doesn't work as C++ (03)

Comment: Same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363759/why-doesnt-this-overloading-namespace-template-related-c-code-compile

Comment: @jthill: Rather, they used to need global linkage for no very good reason, and now they don't.

Comment: @MikeSeymour right, if names in anon namespace can be uniquified then local names certainly should be doable.  Do you happen to know the original rationale for the restriction?

Comment: @jthill: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597463/why-did-c03-require-template-parameters-to-have-external-linkage

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C++03, template arguments could not have internal linkage:

> `[C++03: 14.6.4.2/1]:` For a function call that depends on a template parameter, if the function name is an *unqualified-id* but not a *template-id*, the candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules (3.4.1, 3.4.2) except that:
>
> - **For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup** (3.4.1), **only function declarations with external linkage from the template definition context are found**.
> - For the part of the lookup using associated namespaces (3.4.2), only function declarations with external linkage found in either the template definition context or the template instantiation context are found.
>
> *[..]*

This was changed (issue [#561: "Internal linkage functions in dependent name lookup"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#561)) in C++11:

> `[C++11: C.2.6]:` 14.6.4.2 
>   **Change**: Allow dependent calls of functions with internal linkage 
>   **Rationale:** Overly constrained, simplify overload resolution rules.

resulting in:

> `[C++11: 14.6.4.2/1]:` For a function call that depends on a template parameter, the candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules (3.4.1, 3.4.2, 3.4.3) except that:
>
> - **For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup** (3.4.1) or qualified name lookup (3.4.3), **only function declarations from the template definition context are found.**
> - For the part of the lookup using associated namespaces (3.4.2), only function declarations found in either the template definition context or the template instantiation context are found.
>
> *[..]*

(Spot the missing *"with external linkage"* qualification.)

Since your `main()::ComparitorInner&` has internal linkage, and the instantiation of `std::sort` requires this type to be a template parameter (albeit deduced), your code is only valid in C++11.

Comment: Nice answer, see [number 7 here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23063914/1708801) apparently `clang` allows this in C++03 mode with a warning, which is a little surprising.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Nice answer you!

Comment: I did not intend for that answer to be soo long.

Comment: Hi, I know this is an old answer, but you are quoting the part of the standard for ADL/Koenig lookup, which is not what applies here. The correct section is 14.3.1, which just doesn't allow local types to be used as template arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fine in C++11; there was a restriction about using local types as template arguments in C++03.

Comment: Awesome, that is a restriction I had never run in to before.  The compiler error: no matching function for call to 'sort(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CompareMe**, std::vector<CompareMe*, std::allocator<CompareMe*> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CompareMe**, std::vector<CompareMe*, std::allocator<CompareMe*> > >, main()::ComparitorInner&)'
makes perfect sense now!