# Example of entity declared in a anonymous namespace that has external linkage

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, language-lawyer, linkage

Given the statements below (emphasis mine) in §3.5/4 and in the Note [94] in §7.3.1.1/1, I'd like to have one single example of an entity declared in a unnamed namespace that has external linkage.

§3.5/4

> **An unnamed namespace or a namespace declared directly or indirectly
>   within an unnamed namespace has internal linkage**. All other namespaces
>   have external linkage. **A name having namespace scope that has not been
>   given internal linkage above has the same linkage as the enclosing
>   namespace if it is the name of**
>
> - a variable; or
> - a function; or
> - a named class (Clause 9), or an unnamed class defined in a typedef declaration in which the class has the typedef name for linkage
>     purposes (7.1.3); or
> - a named enumeration (7.2), or an unnamed enumeration defined in a typedef declaration in which the enumeration has the typedef name for
>     linkage purposes (7.1.3); or
> - an enumerator belonging to an enumeration with linkage; or
> - a template.

Note [94] on §7.3.1.1/1:

> Although entities in an unnamed namespace might have external linkage,
>   they are effectively qualified by a name unique to their translation
>   unit and therefore can never be seen from any other translation unit.

Comment: I suspect the footnote may be a leftover from C++03, where names in unnamed namespaces had external linkage (because otherwise they couldn't be used as template parameters). The authors simply forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking at a defect in the standard.

The change that makes unnamed namespace members have internal linkage happened fairly late in the C++11 standardization process, in November 2010 ([CWG issue 1113](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1113)). As a result, a number of places in the standard needs to be changed, but weren't. One of which is the footnote you quoted.

[CWG issue 1603](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1603), currently in "ready" status (read: the resolution is likely to be adopted at the next committee meeting), will fix this and a number of other issues related to giving internal linkage to unnamed namespace members.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good question because it's difficult to demonstrate. We can take advantage of other rules in the C++ Standard to show that a variable in an anonymous namespace can have external linkage.

Templating on an int* with external linkage will succeed while templating on an int* with internal linkage will fail.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace {
    // not externally linked, won't compile
    // const int i = 5;

    // external linkage, compiles
    extern int i;
    int i = 5;
}

template<int* int_ptr>
struct temp_on_extern_linked_int {
    temp_on_extern_linked_int() {
        std::cout << *int_ptr << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    temp_on_extern_linked_int<&i>();
}
```

As shown the program compiles and runs.

```
$ g++-4.8 main.cpp -o main
$ ./main
5
```

Uncommenting the other definition of `i` causes the compile to fail.

```
$ g++-4.8 main.cpp -o main
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:17:30: error: '& {anonymous}::i' is not a valid template argument of
type 'int*' because '{anonymous}::i' does not have external linkage
  temp_on_extern_linked_int<&i>();
                              ^
```

The compiler is quite helpful. It explicitly states that because `i` doesn't have external linkage the compile failed.

The commented definition of `i` has internal linkage because it is qualified const without extern. (§3.4.6)

`Variables at namespace scope that are declared const and not extern have internal linkage.`

Part of the trick is not compiling as C++11.

[Why did C++03 require template parameters to have external linkage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597463/why-did-c03-require-template-parameters-to-have-external-linkage)

Comment: AFAIK you have proved that unnamed namespace had external linkage in C++03, and for that matter you don't even need the declaration `extern int i;`, as the compiler recognizes the declaration `int i = 5;` as having external linkage.

Comment: For C++11 I can only quote to you the standard, but since you already provide the relevant quote in the OP, it's unclear what you're looking for. Does it help to know that a namespace and the variables within do not necessarily have the same linkage?

Comment: Also, what changed in C++11 that breaks the example is template parameters, not linkage rules.

Comment: In C++11 the code compiles because the declaration `extern int i;` doesn't add anything to the declaration `int i = 5;`, i.e., the variable `i` continues to have internal linkage, despite the `extern` specifier.

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
#include <iostream>

namespace
{
    extern int x = 10;

    void f( int y )
    {
        extern int x;
        std::cout << x + y << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    int y =  15;

    f( y );

    return 0;
}
```

According to the C++ Standard

> 6 The name of a function declared in block scope and the name of a
>   variable declared by a block scope extern declaration have linkage. If
>   there is a visible declaration of an entity with linkage having the
>   same name and type, ignoring entities declared outside the innermost
>   enclosing namespace scope, the block scope declaration declares that
>   same entity and receives the linkage of the previous declaration. If
>   there is more than one such matching entity, the program is
>   ill-formed. Otherwise, if no matching entity is found, the block scope
>   entity receives external linkage

Comment: I believe the `or` in §3.5/2 first bullet point is not exclusive. So, I don't agree that `x` has external linkage in your example.

Comment: @Wake up Brazil  x Os automatica variable that is declared with quakifier extern. So if there is preceding declaration of x in the enclosing namespace with linkage then x has the same linkage.See 3.5/6.

Comment: §3.5/6 just tells you that the local `x` has the same linkage as the `x` declared in namespace scope `extern int x = 10;`. But that doesn't imply that this `x` has external linkage. See §3.5/4 first bullet point: `A name having namespace scope that has not
been given internal linkage above has the same linkage as the enclosing namespace if it is the name of — a variable;`. See also §7.1.1/6 that refers to §3.5, regarding the linkage of a name declared with the `extern` specifier.

Comment: @Wake up Brazil it seems you do not understand what you read. Variable x is defined as having external linkage in an unnamed namespace. The local variable declaed in the function has also external linkage because there is a variable with the same name and linkage in the enclosing namespace. What is the problem?!.