# Does a function pointer need to point to a function with external linkage when used as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

In the code below, on the first form, gcc complains about having a lambda in a template parameter.  In the second form, gcc complains about lambda_function_pointer not having external linkage.   Clang compiles and runs the code just fine even with -pedantic.

The `+` in front of the lambda is to coerce it to decay into a function pointer.

```
template<auto f>
void func() {
    f();
}
void g();
int main() {
    func<+[](){}>();  // gcc complains about lambda in template args

    constexpr auto lambda_function_pointer = +[](){};
    func<lambda_function_pointer>(); // gcc complains about not having external linkage

}
```

live: https://godbolt.org/g/ey5uo7

Thank you.

edit: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.lambda#2
 mentions lambdas not appearing in template parameters for the sake of the lambda not being in the signature, but with the `+`, it gets rid of the lambda type.

edit2: This may be relevant for the linkage portion of the question: [Why did C++03 require template parameters to have external linkage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597463/why-did-c03-require-template-parameters-to-have-external-linkage)

Comment: Since you use a C++11 tag, do you expect an answer based on C++11?

Comment: I changed the question title to more accurately reflect the core issue, which is about external linkage. GCC will happily accept the second case, if you move `lambda_function_pointer` to file scope (which gives it external linkage.)

Comment: @NikosC I do not believe that title change is correct. There's more at play here, such as whether the lambda is allowed to appear directly or only through a helper variable, and precisely what is and isn't specified for the implicit conversion to function pointer type.

Comment: @hvd Indeed. I have trouble coming up with a good question title, in order for this to get more attention (it is a very interesting case, imo.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`func<+[](){}>` is ill-formed in C++17 per the exact paragraph you linked to. The non-normative note simply explains the motivation for the normative prohibition. It does not - and cannot - limit it. This restriction has been removed in the current working draft by [P0315](https://wg21.link/P0315), so it has a good chance of making C++20.

Pre-C++17, a *lambda-expression* cannot be evaluated inside constant expressions.

The "linkage" part is a duplicate of [Can I use the result of a C++17 captureless lambda constexpr conversion operator as a function pointer template non-type argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47606810/can-i-use-the-result-of-a-c17-captureless-lambda-constexpr-conversion-operator). It's a GCC bug.

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry the question was confusing at first.